# VSCode execute node script on remote linux or windows machine

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, visual-studio-code

Using VSCode, is it possible to execute a node.js script on a remote linux or windows system without setting up a full *Visual Studio Code Remote Development Environment*?

Assume the following:

- VSCode installed on client (Windows)
- remote system is a virtual machine running on the client. It has access to the project folder (including the script to be executed and the node modules) on the client. Node is installed on the remote system.

Actually I just need something like a launch configuration which executes an SSH command for linux, for windows maybe something else. With these assumptions (shared project folder between remote system and client), is that possible without setting up a full *Visual Studio Code Remote Development Environment*? I don't need remote editing or debugging.

Comment: Are you writing your code on your System A and then trying to execute that file on System B via ssh? Is this what you want to do? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh